# Read 4D arrays from two binary files and write into a single one

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, fortran, binaryfiles

Anyone knows how to read and write two unformatted binary files (each one having a 4-dimensional variable) into a single .bin file with the same dimensions?

I am trying this, but without success (I am new to Fortran):

```
program teste
implicit none
real, dimension(144,73,12,4) :: air,hgt
integer :: l,k,reclen
real :: irec

inquire(iolength=reclen)air
open(1,file='air.bin',status='old',form='unformatted',access='direct',action='read',recl=reclen)
open(2,file='hgt.bin',status='old',form='unformatted',access='direct',action='read',recl=reclen)
open(3,file='air_hgt.bin',form='unformatted',access='direct',action='write',recl=reclen)

read(1,rec=1)air
read(2,rec=1)hgt
close(1)
close(2)

irec=0

do l=1,4
  do k=1,12
    irec=irec+1
    write(3,rec=irec)air(:,:,k,l)
  end do
  do k=1,12
    irec=irec+1
    write(3,rec=irec)hgt(:,:,k,l)
  end do
end do
close(3)
end program teste
```

When I run the code, the compiler never stops running, even though the .bin files are very small (2MB each). So, after a few minutes, I force it to stop running and the file created is very large (hundreds of gigabytes). Doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "without success" - edit the question

Comment: Do air.bin and hgt.bin have the same record length and the same number of records?  How were air.bin and hgt.bin created?

Comment: @IanBush I added some explanations about the problem there, thanks.

Comment: @evets Yes, the .bin files have the same record length and number of records. I think they were created from NetCDF files, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If the files were written as NetCDF files, the files have more structure than just having the arrays.  You will have to use the NetCDF library to read them.  I suggest not just guessing about the origin of the files.  Perhaps examine the files with a hex editor.   Conversely, if the files are simpler than NetCDR, I'd try access=stream rather than access=direct.and just read and write sequentially rather than specify the record.

Comment: Just to back up M.S.B. you have to know how these files were written - Fortran has no simple way to help you read a file of unknown origin. If they were written using netcf you will almost certainly have to use netcdf to read them.